# Parallelize nonlinear regression using multiprocessing or MPI

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi, python-multiprocessing

I have a simple nonlinear regression. It runs sequentially fine except for taking long time to complete. The process can speed up using MPI or multiprocess. How should I approach applying them to run my code?

Here is my code for nonlinear regression:

```
data = pd.read_csv('....csv')
X = data.iloc[:, 0]
Y = data.iloc[:, 1]

#Model build
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

L = 0.0001  
epochs = 10000  

n = float(len(X)) 

#Perform Gradient Descent 
for i in range(epochs): 
    Y_pred = a*X*X + b*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
    D_a = (-2/n) * sum(X*X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt a
    D_b = (-2/n) * sum(X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt b
    D_c = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
    a = a - L * D_a  # Update a
    b = b - L * D_b  # Update b
    c = c - L * D_c  # Update c
print (a, b, c)

#Predictions
Y_pred = a*X*X + b*X + c
```

Comment: If you can provide a sample data you are using it will be easier for us to reproduce your problem and help you.
Also which part would you like to parallelize ? Gradient descent is sequential by nature, you need the parameters from previous step in order to make update at the current step

Comment: Your loop over the epochs can not be parallelized. You can speed this up a little by moving the `X*X` computation outside the loop. Btw, I hope you are using `numpy`? If you are using native python arrays/lists your process will be 100x slower.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout yes I'm using numpy. I wondered if it is possible to run it with mpi4py

Comment: Yes, numpy is the best way to use mpi & python for array applications.

Answer (score 0):

Gradient descent is sequential by nature, you need the parameters from previous step in order to make update at the current step.

Few optimizations you can add to improve your code include using numpy arrays instead of pandas series, and also moving the X*X outside the for loop as suggested by @Victor Eijkhout. Here's a minimal working example :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

# generate a fake dataset
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": np.random.randn(10_000),
    "y": np.random.randn(10_000)
})


def train_v1(data):
    X = data.iloc[:, 0]
    Y = data.iloc[:, 1]

    #Model build
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0

    L = 0.0001
    epochs = 10_000

    n = float(len(X)) 

    #Perform Gradient Descent 
    for i in range(epochs): 
        Y_pred = a*X*X + b*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
        D_a = (-2/n) * sum(X*X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt a
        D_b = (-2/n) * sum(X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt b
        D_c = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
        a = a - L * D_a  # Update a
        b = b - L * D_b  # Update b
        c = c - L * D_c  # Update c
    print (a, b, c)

    
def train_v2(data):
    X = data.iloc[:, 0].values
    Y = data.iloc[:, 1].values
    X_square = X*X

    #Model build
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0

    L = 0.0001
    epochs = 10000

    n = float(len(X)) 

    #Perform Gradient Descent 
    for i in range(epochs): 
        Y_pred = a*X_square + b*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
        D_a = (-2/n) * np.sum(X_square * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt a
        D_b = (-2/n) * np.sum(X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt b
        D_c = (-2/n) * np.sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
        a = a - L * D_a  # Update a
        b = b - L * D_b  # Update b
        c = c - L * D_c  # Update c
    print (a, b, c)
```

I created two functions :

- `train_v1` which is exactly the code you provided
- `train_v2` with some optimisations

```py
%%timeit
train_v1(data)
```

Output :

```
0.004405914780579786 0.004665404814519434 0.005183005935438013
0.004405914780579786 0.004665404814519434 0.005183005935438013
0.004405914780579786 0.004665404814519434 0.005183005935438013
0.004405914780579786 0.004665404814519434 0.005183005935438013
0.004405914780579786 0.004665404814519434 0.005183005935438013
0.004405914780579786 0.004665404814519434 0.005183005935438013
0.004405914780579786 0.004665404814519434 0.005183005935438013
0.004405914780579786 0.004665404814519434 0.005183005935438013
16.6 s ± 342 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
%%timeit
train_v2(data)
```

Output :

```
0.0044059147805797835 0.004665404814519433 0.005183005935438011
0.0044059147805797835 0.004665404814519433 0.005183005935438011
0.0044059147805797835 0.004665404814519433 0.005183005935438011
0.0044059147805797835 0.004665404814519433 0.005183005935438011
0.0044059147805797835 0.004665404814519433 0.005183005935438011
0.0044059147805797835 0.004665404814519433 0.005183005935438011
0.0044059147805797835 0.004665404814519433 0.005183005935438011
0.0044059147805797835 0.004665404814519433 0.005183005935438011
408 ms ± 2.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see the gain is huge `408 milliseconds` for the optimized code VS `16.6 seconds` four your original code.

Comment: Change `Y_pred = a*X*X + b*X + c` to also use `X_square` and `train_v2()` will get a small performance improvement.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks @DanNagle I missed that one, I updated the code to include your changes and indeed the performance goes from `428 ms` to  `408 ms`  :)

Comment: thank you! That's quite an improvement from what I did. I was wondering if it's possible to work with mpi4py?

Comment: @Telecaster as stated in the answer, gradient descent is sequential by nature, so I don't see how you can parallelize the steps. All you can do is to optimize the block of code that runs a  single step update so that running it in for loop becomes faster. You may consider using [GPU](https://rapids.ai/) if your use-case is much more complex than the example you posted here, because generally GPU is faster than CPU in terms of matrix operations

Comment: @Alka how about just distribute the data to multiple proccessors. Each processor will do the computation for each batch of data then perform a combination at the end

Comment: well, numpy is already heavily optimized for matrix computation. Unless you have a "really special" usecase I don't see the benefit of distributing your computations as the performance gain maybe quite small. But if you want to dig deeper into this, you can search for the distribution algorithms used in deep learning in case of very large models / Big datasets